# Login in pop-up using Selenium and Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to login on a [website](http://www.qassa-nl.be) using the selenium webdriver in Python 3. First, I need to click the button "Inloggen", after which I need to fill in username and password and than click the (new) button "Inloggen" again. 
So, I've tried to locate the first "Inloggen" button (with the code below), and tried to .click() it, but then it raises an error "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: ", but without message.

```
from selenium import webdriver

# go to login page and sign in
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.qassa-nl.be/")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@title='Inloggen']").click()
```

Secondly, if this works, I can send my login keys using the classic way I guess.

Best,

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

Here is the working code block which will open the url `https://www.qassa-nl.be/`, click on button `Inloggen`, fills up `email`, fills up `password` and finally clicks on `Inloggen` button:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe')
caps = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
caps["marionette"] = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=caps, firefox_binary=binary, executable_path="C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.qassa-nl.be/")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='personal_info']//a[text()='Inloggen']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='login_username']").send_keys("debanjan")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='login_password']").send_keys("debanjan")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@title='Inloggen']").click()
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the suggested answer. Can you explain me why my method didn't work, and yours does? And can it also work with PhantomJS?

Comment: @Tim I have simply accessed the url `https://www.qassa-nl.be/` through `get()` method. Now the script will look for an element with xpath as  `//div[@id='personal_info']//a[text()='Inloggen']` first & click on it. Next, the script will look for an element with xpath as  `//input[@id='login_username']` & send the text `debanjan`. Again, the script will look for an element with xpath as  `//input[@id='login_password']` & send the text `debanjan`. Finally, the script will look for an element with xpath as  `//button[@title='Inloggen']` & click it. Thanks

Comment: Hmmm, also, after updating the paths, I got an error on the page load timeout: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unrecognised timeout: page load.

Comment: Also, I could not really get the first 5 lines of code (imports not included); from the driver.get I already used in the past. Thanks!

Comment: @Tim Please don't bother about the first 5 lines. Testers normally try to put in the exe files and Browser exe in Selenium's convenient location within their system which is easily picked up by Selenium. Where as, as I work with multiple versions of exe files and multiple versions of same browser, so I call them explicitly in my code where ever, whenever & whichever version is needed. Thanks

Comment: This is weird, I got an unexpected error from the send_keys: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Expected [object Undefined] undefined to be a string -- while, I normally do it in exactly the same way?

Comment: @Tim Please consider bumping up your Selenium to 3.4.3, geckodriver to v0.17.0 & Mozilla Firefox to 53.0 (stable, GA). Things will be fine with you. Thanks

Comment: @Tim There was no other possibility :) the code was well tested on my machine. Glad to be able to help you. Thanks